# Correct approach to UserControl creation when using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

This is more of a conceptual question rather than a practical one. I'm just starting to learn the MVVM concept for developing UI , and I've come across a dillema I'm not sure the answer to: 
Say I have a main window and a little pop-up window (meaning it's a small window with some UI elements in it). The structure of the program will look something like this:

**MainWindow** 
 
model <-- MainWindowViewModel.cs <-- MainWindowView.xaml (containing no code-behind)

**PopUpWindow** (A UserControl)
model <-- PopUpWindowViewModel.cs <-- PopUpWindowView.xaml (containing no code-behind)

*the model is just a bunch of BL classes that are irrelevant for this question.

Now , lets say I want to create a new PopUp window from inside the MainWindowViewModel (or even save an instance of it in a private data-member). What is the correct way of doing so?
The way I see it I can't do something like this :

```
PopUpWindow pop = new PopUpWindow()
```

Because it kind of defeats the purpose of abstracting the view from the view model(What if a year from now i'll want to create a better version of the PopUpWindow using the same PopUpWindowViewModel?).
On the other hand , I can't initialize a new instnace of the PopUpWindow using just it's view model (The viewModel as I understand is not supposed to know anything about the view that will use it).

Hope it all makes sense... so what would you do in that situation?

*Just to clarify it further , let's say for argument's sake that the situation I'm describing is a button on the MainWindowView that upon clicking will open a PopUpWindowView.

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: I think you will find that the code you wind up writing to get you the separation of concerns you are looking for will be closer to Model-View-Presenter. The views should be handling the click events and firing off messages or calling callbacks that are passed into their constructor. The view doesn't or shouldn't care about what code gets run, but know what to do once the click happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat a similar dilemma and I'll explain how I solved it.

Let's say you have `MainWindow` and a `SettingsWindow`, which you want to display when the `SettingsButton` is clicked.

You have two respective view models, `MainWindowViewModel` and `SettingsViewModel`, which you will be passing as their `Window.DataContext` properties.

Your `MainWindowViewModel` should expose an `ICommand` property named `SettingsButtonCommand` (or similar). Bind this command to the `SettingsButton.Command`.

Now your command should invoke something like this:

```
void OnSettingsButtonClicked()
{
    var viewModel = new SettingsViewModel();
    var window = new SettingsWindow();

    window.DataContext = viewModel;
    window.Show();
}
```

There is a slight issue when you want to use `Window.ShowDialog()`, because you need to resume execution.

For these cases I have an asynchronous variant of the [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html):

```
public sealed class AsyncDelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Func<object, Task> onExecute;
    readonly Predicate<object> onCanExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public AsyncDelegateCommand(Func<object, Task> onExecute)
        : this(onExecute, null) { }

    public AsyncDelegateCommand(Func<object, Task> onExecute, Predicate<object> onCanExecute)
    {
        if (onExecute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("onExecute");

        this.onExecute = onExecute;
        this.onCanExecute = onCanExecute;
    }

    #region ICommand Methods

    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        await onExecute(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return onCanExecute != null ? onCanExecute(parameter) : true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've specifically said that the popup is a UserControl so you can use basic data templating. First create view models for your main window and popup control:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private PopUpViewModel _PopUp;
    public PopUpViewModel PopUp
    {
        get { return _PopUp; }
        set { _PopUp = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.PopUp); }
    }       
}

public class PopUpViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _Message; }
        set { _Message = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Message); }
    }
}
```

The MainViewModel's PopUp member is initially null, we'll set it to an instance of PopUpViewModel when we want the popup to appear. To do that we create a content control on the main window and set it's content to that member. We also use a data template to specify the type of child control to create when the popup view model has been set:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PopUpViewModel}">
        <local:PopUpWindow />
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Show PopUp" Click="Button_Click_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding PopUp}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I'm doing a big no-no here by creating the view model in the code-behind along with a click handler, but it's just for illustrative purposes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainViewModel VM = new MainViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this.VM;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.VM.PopUp = new PopUpViewModel { Message = "Hello World!" };
    }
}
```

That's it! Click the button, popup window appears underneath it showing the content. Now it may not always be this simple, sometimes you may want to create multiple children on a parent control...in that case you'd set up an ItemsControl, set its panel to a Grid (say) and modify the data templates to set the Margin etc on each element to position them. Or you may not always know what type of view model is going to be created, in which case you need to add multiple data templates for each type you're expecting. Either way you still have good separation of concerns because it is the views that are deciding how to display the content in the view models. The view models themselves still don't know anything about the views and they can be unit-tested etc independently.